# Error while updating property 'placeholder' of a view managed by: AndroidTextInput

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, jsx

I am trying to access prop inside of native-base Item component and it throws

```
    Error while updating property 'placeholder' of a view managed
    by:AndroidTextInput

    TypeError: expected dynamic type `string', but had type `int64'
```

Here's the code which returns this error

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, Content, Form, Item, Input, Button, Text } from 'native-base';

export default class EditProduct extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    Actions.refresh({
     title: 'Edit Product',
     leftTitle: '<',
     onLeft: () => {},
   });
}

render() {
  const id = this.props.id || 'No ID';
  const min = this.props.min || 'No Min';
  const max = this.props.max || 'No Max';

  return (
    <Container>
     <Content>
      <Form>
        <Item>
          <Input placeholder=id />
        </Item>
        <Item>
          <Input placeholder=max />
        </Item>
        <Item last>
          <Input placeholder=min />
        </Item>

        <Button block>
          <Text>Confirm</Text>
        </Button>
      </Form>
     </Content>
   </Container>
 );
 }
}
```

How do I convert string from int64? Is there any alternative to this than converting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input's props placeholder receive string, just simply covert it to string.

```
const id = this.props.id + ""
```